# How to build a project using MAKE, on Windows? (It builds output from source JS files)

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, makefile

So, I am trying to build this on Windows:

https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar/

I have Visual Studio 2012, and I tried opening the developer tools command prompt, going to the folder where I where I have a clone of the above repository, and where the makefile exists, and run NMAKE, I got this:

I got:

> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.51106.1
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> makefile(12) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '{'
>   in macro Stop.

I haven't used anything MAKE related before, but I heard this can be problematic on Windows. I'm assuming it's a general problem rather than a repository specific problem (it's a fork of a popular repository, and didn't seem to change the build related files since forked). Not sure where to start.

Any ideas?

.

**Update:**

I noticed this required Java to be installed and included in PATH environment variable as per the readme, and the right command to run was `make zip`, I tried `nmake zip` after ensuring Java bin was in the PATH, and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Makefile uses a lot of more-complex constructs that Windows's `cmd.exe` can't handle. I'd advise trying to run it in MinGW or Cygwin if you need it to run on Windows.

Comment: I have Msysgit, would that work? It doesn't seem to recognize `make` as a known command. Do I need to install anything after I get cygwin? (I don't know MinGW) -Thanks

Comment: @MohamedMeligy: When you install Cygwin, it lets you select from a list of packages. From looking at the Makefile, I think you'll need at least `coreutils`, `bash`, `make`, `sed`, and `findutils`. It also needs `git` and `java`, but it may be able to pick up your already-installed versions of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was the right way. I needed also to include the `zip` explicitly as well, and for some reason run CygWin as administrator, and it worked like a charm. Really appreciate it.